# Tallis falling off 

Tags: blessing, tallit-gadol

What happens if your tallis falls off, is a bracha required?

Answer (score 2):

Both according to Sephardim and Ashkenazim it depends on whether or not you realized it was falling off, and thus had intention to put it back on immediately or not.  See Shulahan Arukh [8:15](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14170&st=&pgnum=29), and the Mishnah Berurah, as well as the Kaf HaHaim [there](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14418&st=&pgnum=47&hilite=) , and Ben Ish Hai [Year 1 Berashit 10](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40322&st=&pgnum=11) .

The reasoning behind the Kaf HaHaim and Ben Ish Hai is that a second Berakha would be a Berakha sofek l'vatala, and thus should not be said.  However, if it falls off without your knowledge and there was no immediate intention to put it back on then it appears another Berakha is required.

Comment: I can't speak for the Sephardim, but I don't think Ashkenazim make that distinction.  Only when your intent is to take it off and return it, no beracha is said.  But if you don't want it to fall off, I don't know that daas to return it while it's falling works.  See mishna berura 39 whose svara applies even when you realize (everyone's stam daas is to put their talis back on if it falls).

Comment: I just looked at the Kaf haChaim.  He, too, does not make the distinction.  He says you don't make a bracha at all when it falls off because of safek brachos, unlike the Ashkenazim.  The Ben Ish Chai does not talk at all about a talis falling off.  He only talks about taking it off intentionally.  So we don't know where he stands in our case.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard the shulchan aruch says that if it totally fell off, then yes, you'd make a new bracha when putting it back on.  Your intent with your first bracha did not include this sudden interruption.

Comment: My brother is saying his bar mitzvah speech on this topic and he said that that was the exact awnser.

Comment: So you were looking to quiz us here?

Answer (score 1):

If one's tallit or tzitzit fall entirely off, he must recite a new blessing before putting them back on. This is true even if he picks it up and puts it back on immediately.

Among Sephardic Jews, one who removes his tallit intentionally must recite a new blessing before putting it back on. Among Ashkenazic Jews, though, one who intentionally removes the tallit need not recite a blessing before putting it back on, so long as he did not travel far and did not wait a long time before putting it back on. It is difficult to define "a long time;" ask your local authority for more information.

(Code of Jewish Law Orach Chaim 8:14-15; Mishneh Berurah 8:40)

from Mordechai - 
http://halachahbyemail.blogspot.com/2010/11/if-tallit-falls-off.html

Comment: The bit about Sephardim is not true. The Maran does not rule that way, neither does the Ben Ish Hai, the Kaf HaHaim, or the Yalkut Yosef.

Comment: Sorry the Maran does rule that way, but the Sephardim Poskim rule according to the Rema in this case.